# With Spring, can I load a property from application.yml for the value of an anotation parameter

Tags: spring

With spring boot, can I load a property from application.yml for the value of an anotation parameter, like this:

```
@Document(collection = "${mongodb.collectionNames.product}")
public class Product {
...
```

Comment: Give it a try and see what happens

Comment: Sure, I tried that, It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If the annotation logic doens't implement this, you cannot do it.